# invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c, string

```
int ::  cadena calculatelenght(const cadena& a, const char* cad)
{
    cadena c;
    int lenght = 0;
    char* punt; punt = cad;
    while(*punt){
        lenght++; punt++;
    }
    return lenght;
}
```

I have this problem, I want to calculate the length of a C string without using functions like `strlen`, in other methods of my cadena class I can because is not const char*, but now I don't know what to do.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `-fpermissive`. If it's normally an error, you shouldn't compile it.

Comment: I'm using code blocks IDE and is the default compilation mode

Comment: What's wrong with `strlen(punt)`? Or `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` for `c.pstr`? A lot of these loops and variables look like they would go away with simple use of some standard templates.

Comment: The default compilation mode allows you to write erroneous code?

Comment: Is this homework? If not, what reasons do you have for not using functions like strlen?

Comment: I'm simply practicing this, is homework and I want to learn a little more than using those predefined functions xD

Comment: Please *reduce your code to a minimum*, and post a *complete* example that exhibits the behaviour. It’s annoying that we now have to read through lines of irrelevant code in order to find your problem. Also, choosing better variable names is essential to help understanding.

Comment: Yes, sorry but I'm a real noob xDD

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm willing to bet that the variable names in the original example make perfect sense! Just not to you or me.

Comment: @Mr Lister: just spanish names of strings and lenght etc.

Comment: @freinn Much better (except for the fact that now you’ve made a copy&paste error).

Comment: `int ::  cadena calculatelenght` is not valid C/C++. Do you mean
the C++ `int cadena::calculatelenght`?

Comment: I'd like to clarify that [-fpermissive] is NOT enabled by default. This shows in the compiler error log as a suggestion if you want to ignore the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can declare `punt` to be of the correct type:

```
const char * punt = cad;
```

Comment: Why can you (and me) do this?? because is a const?? a normal pointer cant initialize at the same time

Comment: Sure it can! Why did you think not?

Comment: @freinn: For any type `T`, the type `T *` is convertible to `T const *` (which is the same as `const T *`), but the opposite conversion is not allowed, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
const char* punt; punt = cad;
```

Comment: Omg!! I didn't think that, then why we say this pointer is "const" when I move it to calculate the lenght?? :S:S

Comment: @freinn you can still move a pointer that points to something `const`, that `const char*` just means you can't modify _what the pointer points to_. If you want a pointer that you can't _move_ but that you can modify what it points to, then you do `char* const`, and if you want a pointer that both you can't move and you can't modify what it points to, you need `const char* const`

Comment: @freinn: You can't change the value of the object that it points at, but you can change where it points to.

Comment: @dreamlax, I don't understand why you said: "The default compilation mode allows you to write erroneous code?"