# error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I get the following error:

```
2 smartcard.c: In member function ‘virtual bool cSmartCards::ParseLine(const char*, bool)’:
3 smartcard.c:1187:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
4    char *r=index(line,':');
5                          ^
```

The code is:

```
1184
1185 bool cSmartCards::ParseLine(const char *line, bool fromCache)
1186 {
1187   char *r=index(line,':');
1188   if(!r) return false;
```

I included `"string.h"`

How can I rewrite line 1187?

index() can be found in string.h.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - You're asking questions about a function we can't see!

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid conversion from ‘const char\*’ to ‘char\*’ \[-fpermissive\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200268/invalid-conversion-from-const-char-to-char-fpermissive)

Comment: index can be found in sting.h!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the following:

```
 Function index is found in string.h.
 Change line 1187 to: const char *r=index(line,':');
```

Answer (score 5):

Either or both of the following:

- `index` returns `const char*`, not a `char*`. So, make `r` a `const char*`, not a `char*`.
- The function `index` is written to expect a `char*`, not a `const char*`. I cannot safely suggest a fix for this without knowing what `index` is and does.

Comment: Bad question/good answer. The usual 98% to 2% ratio we see here.

Comment: Great! Thanks! The first suggestion works perfectly!

Comment: @musbach `index()` is in [`string.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)`??

Comment: Of course therefore I inserted that I include sting.h? Didn't you know?